# Android studio - How to create curved lines with animation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I want to create a layout with animation curved lines like this link:

https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1032798/screenshots/4981336/untitled-1.gif?vid=1

[image]

Comment: The better approach will be creating your own After Effects animation and render it in android application using Lottie library https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android .

Comment: and how can i draw these lines before animate them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with a custom view and draw my own path

```
class DrawView : View {
    ...

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        path = Path()
        paint.color = Color.RED
        paint.strokeWidth = 3f
        path.moveTo(34f, 259f)
        path.cubicTo(68f, 151f, 286f, 350f, 336f, 252f)
        canvas.drawPath(path!!, paint!!)
    }
}
```

This ends up into

[image]

Now you have to make this parameterize, to make it animate-able.
To do so, it's quite easy to use a [MotionLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/motion/MotionLayout)

Here is the [code](https://github.com/hannesa2/curvedLines)

Comment: Here is the running sample https://github.com/hannesa2/curvedLines

Comment: can u send source code again ,it not available now.
I am trying to animated My DrawView corners points when a new points arrives @hannes-ach